# how to show Android Application only for Handset or Phone not for tablet in Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, android-screen-support

I am developing application where minsdk 8 and targetsdk 23 which is only support phone device screen not for tablet so, i required some attribute in manifest for phone or handset only so, Google play store apply correct filtering based on attributes in manifest and application is only available for phone not for tablet. i have searched regarding that i have found Android official doc that says  supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"

**Caution:** The Android system does not pay attention to this attribute, so it does not affect how your application behaves at runtime. Instead, it is used to enable filtering for your application on services such as Google Play. However, Google Play currently does not support this attribute for filtering (on Android 3.2), so you should continue using the other size attributes if your application does not support small screens. but as per doc says in Caution Google Play currently does not support this attribute for filtering. so i m confused so, what attributes are required in manifest for support in Phone screen.please help me to solve this issue.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [link](http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html#support-screens)

I think you need to set             android:xlargeScreens="false"

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="false"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Comment: but Android doc says Android 3.2 introduces new attributes for the <supports-screens> manifest element: android:requiresSmallestWidthDp

Comment: my minsdk 8 and targetsdk 23

Comment: thanks for your answer i think a link mentioned its not clear but something learned from that

Comment: if my minsdk 14 and targetsdk 23 than what attribute should be its same as you mentioned or else

Comment: Regarding `android:xlargeScreens="false"`, as per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#xlarge): `Beware that setting it "false" will generally enable screen compatibility mode.`

Answer (score 0):

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Also you need to specify tvdpi, xxhdpi, and xxxhdpi devices if intended to support those devices too.

Comment: but Android doc says  Android 3.2 introduces new attributes for the <supports-screens> manifest element:
android:requiresSmallestWidthDp

Comment: so your mentioned attributes will work in google play store filtering are you sure? my minsdk 8 and targetsdk 23

Comment: thanks for your answer but if my minsdk 14 and targetsdk 23 than what attribute should be its same as you mentioned or else